# Intersection cohomology and Poincaré duality

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, perverse-sheaves, intersection-cohomology

When trying to learn about perverse sheaves I hand-wavingly thought that intersection cohomology is the ‘minimal’ way of fixing the failure of Poincaré duality. But I am very aware that it is risky to try to encode grand ideas in such simple thoughts. This led me to ponder the following question.

$\DeclareMathOperator\IC{IC}$Given, for example, a complex connected projective variety, $X$, such that $\IC(X) = \mathbb{C}_{X}[\dim X]$ then it satisfies Poincaré duality. However is the converse true? Does Poincaré duality being satisfied imply that $\IC(X) = \mathbb{C}_{X}[\dim X]$? If not then this would suggest I was right to be wary of my own intuition.

I am still nowhere near capable enough with perverse sheaves to gain an answer to this so any answers would be appreciated and of great interest.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve and let $Y$ be the union of two $\mathbb P^1$s joined by a node (say, the solution set of $xy = 0$ in $\mathbb Z/2$).

Let $\sigma$ be an involution of $E \times Y$ that acts on $E$ by translation by a two-torsion point and acts on $Y$ by swapping the two copies of $\mathbb P^1$.

Then $X= (E \times Y)/\sigma$ is a counterexample. Since $\sigma$ acts trivially on the cohomology of $E$, we have

$$ H^* ( X)= H^* ( E \times Y )^{\sigma} = (H^*(E) \otimes H^*(Y) )^\sigma = H^*(E) \otimes H^*(Y)^\sigma = H^*(E) \otimes H^*(Y/\sigma) = H^*(E) \otimes H^*(\mathbb P^1),$$ which satisfies Poincaré duality, and all the identities I used were compatible with cup product so $X$ does as well.

However, the condition that the IC sheaf is the constant sheaf is a local condition. Since $\sigma$ acts on $E$ without fixed points, $\sigma$ acts on $E \times Y$ for fixed points, and thus this condition holds for $X$ if and only if it holds for $E \times Y$. But it does not hold for $E \times Y$ as the IC sheaf is the sum of the constant sheaves on the two $E \times \mathbb P^1$s, and is not itself the constant sheaf (or, alternatively, because $E \times Y$ does not satisfy Poincaré duality).

Comment: Fantastic. Thank you